# Applied forces on a bridge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

- What are the forces that acted on the 6 types of bridges?
- Beam, Truss, Cantilever, Arch, Suspension, and Cable-Stay?
- What formulas do you use to get the forces?

I'm curious since there is nothing on the internet about it. Please help me with this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: This E-book might help-https://books.google.co.in/books?id=734x25duZRUC&lpg=PA301&ots=Z0ekUSiPDX&dq=forces%20acting%20on%206%20bridge%20types&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=forces%20acting%20on%206%20bridge%20types&f=false